# Piranha CMS Login issue

Tags: piranha-cms

I am using Piranha CMS , and i want to create multiple users in different group, i tried to do so but its not allowing me to login those users,even i have to implement that logged in user should only edit few pages which is permitted to that user. How can i restrict user to do so

Comment: if question is not related to reders interest please do not down vote to it

Answer (score 1):

The group permission system in Piranha CMS is hierarchical, this means that all users that should be able to log in to the manager should derive from the group **admin**.

When you have that set up you can take a look at the different **permissions** in the manager interface and assign these to different groups.

There are however no support to allow users to only edit certain pages, if you want that kind of behavior you'll have to implement it yourself in the available manager hooks.

Regards